# SQL Server on real server

Tags: sql-server

For a project, I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to run my database. I connect to this through localhost.
I have written an application using Qt which use this database, but now I am distribute the application. How do I change my database on localhost so that I can connect to it from other computers and have multiple connection to the database at the same time.

Comment: Check out this post - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-2-connecting-from-another-computer

Comment: If default installation is done and there's no firewall issue, using the hostname or IP address of the server machine should do the job. In case any specific instance is created then [192.168.xxx.xxx\INSTANCE_NAME] should be used. If its not working then @ScottHodgin already provided the reference.

Comment: The thing that bites a lot of people is not having TCP/IP protocol enabled

Comment: Is localhost your personal PC?  What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: @JohnEisbrener Local host is my personal PC, and im using SQL Server 2016

Comment: You are not allowed to run production workloads via SQL Server Developer edition, which it sounds like you may be looking at doing.  If you need a free edition of SQL Server, look at Express, though I would always caution running production workloads from a personal computer.  Pay options are either Standard or Enterprise (or Web if you go through a hosting provider).  [More info can be found here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2016-pricing)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to check is if Remote access is enabled on your SQL Server instance. 
If not please configure by following the steps [here](https://community.sophos.com/kb/zh-cn/118473).

Comment: How does this help answer the question? This setting is for the deprecated remote access feature (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option). Are you perhaps thinking of enabling remote connections using SQL Server Configuration Manager?

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks, i changed my answer based on your comment.